# javascript array push anon function fails

Tags: javascript, push

here's one something i ran into today.

ok

```
[].push(
  function() {return 1;},
);
```

not ok

```
[].push(
  function() {return 1;},
  function() {return 1;},
);
```

anyone know what's going on here?

thanks!

Comment: the extra `,` in your first example?

Comment: what makes you think the second one is not ok but the first one is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both work fine as long as there is no trailing comma after the last argument:

```
[].push(
  function() {return 1;},
  function() {return 1;}
);
```

Comment: wow, should have caught that one myself. guess i'm too used to keeping trailing commas in that style of array notation. thx. must be early, time for coffee.

Comment: @leeoniya Glad I could help.  Enjoy your coffee :P

Comment: btw, what's the etiquette on SO for keeping these silly-mistake questions? i don't think this is worth keeping around as it would provide little value to others. should i delete the question?

Comment: @leeoniya Nope, you should leave it around.  If the community decides to delete it then it will be deleted, but it will probably stay around just in case it ever does benefit someone in the future.  It doesn't hurt anything being left up.

Comment: @leeoniya: be careful about extra commas in array notation. Some browsers ignore them for convenience but IE doesn't (so this can be a source of hard to find bugs).

Comment: @missingno, thanks i'm aware of this. this particular project does not need to work in IE and would need an impossibly huge ie-fallback codebase to do so - it's for an internal tool.

Comment: @leeoniya: Well, it would just be a matter of running the codebase through jshint in this case though...